# Find the Relationship Between Two Logarithmic Equations

Tags: equation, logarithm

No idea if I am asking this question in the right place, but here goes...

I have a set of equations that were calculated based on numbers ranging from 4 to 8. So an equation for when this number is 5, one for when it is 6, one for when it is 7, etc. These equations were determined from graphing a best fit line to data points in a Google Sheet graph. Here is an example of a graph...
[image: Example Graph]

Example...

When the number is between 6 and 6.9, this equation is used: `windGust6to7 = -29.2 + (17.7 * log(windSpeed))`

When the number is between 7 and 7.9, this equation is used: `windGust7to8 = -70.0 + (30.8 * log(windSpeed))`

I am using these equations to create an image in python, but the image is too choppy since each equation covers a range from x to x.9. In order to smooth this image out and make it more accurate, I really would need an equation for every 0.1 change in number. So an equation for 6, a different equation for 6.1, one for 6.2, etc.

Here is an example output image that is created using the current equations:
[image: Example Output Image]

So my question is: Is there a way to find the relationship between the two example equations I gave above in order to use that to create a smoother looking image?

Comment: This isn't really to do with [tag:python].

Answer (score 0):

This is not about logarithms; for the purposes of this derivation, `log(windspeed)` is a constant term.  Rather, you're trying to find a fit for your mapping:

```
6   (-29.2, 17.7)
7   (-70.0, 30.8)
...
```

... and all of the other numbers you have already.  You need to determine two basic search paramteres:

(1) Where in each range is your function an exact fit?  For instance, for the first one, is it *exactly* correct at 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, or elsewhere?  Change the left-hand column to reflect that point.
(2) What sort of fit do you want?  You are basically fitting a pair of parameterized equations, one for each coefficient:

```
x     y            x    y
6   -29.2          6   17.7
7   -70.0          7   30.8
```

For each of these, you want to find the coefficients of a good matching function.  This is a large field of statistical and algebraic study.  Since you have four ranges, you will have four points for each function.  It is straightforward to fit a cubic equation to each set of points in Cartesian space.  However, the resulting function may not be as smooth as you like; in such a case, you may well find that a 4th- or 5th- degree function fits better, or perhaps something exponential, depending on the actual distribution of your points.

You need to work with your own problem objectives and do a little more research into function fitting.  Once you determine the desired characteristics, look into `scikit` for fitting functions to do the heavy computational work for you.

Comment: Thanks, @Prune. I will look into that. It is exactly correct at the whole number 6.0, 7.0, etc.